# localStorage concatenating Integer instead of adding

Tags: javascript, local-storage

Trying to simply store a variable using localStorage, retrieve it later on as an integer, add it to another integer and then store it again. However, it seems to be treating the integer as a string and concatenates numbers instead. I have tried using JSON.stringify and parse but it doesn't work and I can't see why. (the variable `hours` is definitely an integer.)

```
 if (localStorage.getItem('hours_worked') === null) {
       localStorage.setItem('hours_worked', JSON.stringify(hours));  
   }
 else {
       var temp_hours = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('hours_worked'));
       var temp_hours1 = temp_hours + hours;
       alert(temp_hours1);
       localStorage.setItem('hours_worked', JSON.stringify(temp_hours1));  
   }
```

I'm sure I'm missing something really obvious so if someone could point it out to me that would be fantastic, thanks!

Comment: How does your JSON look like? Seems like you have a string and not a number. Call `parseInt(..., 10)` or `Number(...)`. Better?

Comment: Thanks, yeah I had played around with parseInt but couldn't get it to work before, thanks for pointing me in the right direction, it's all sorted now!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

localStorage treats everything as a string. You have to parseInt its value before using it as an Integer.

Besides, you should use the JSON Stringify to convert array to strings. Your variable hours is an Int so you don't need the Stringify it.

```
if (localStorage.getItem('hours_worked') === null) {
   localStorage.setItem('hours_worked', hours);  
}
else {
   var temp_hours = parseInt(localStorage.getItem('hours_worked'),10);
   var temp_hours1 = temp_hours + hours;
   alert(temp_hours1);
   localStorage.setItem('hours_worked', temp_hours1);  
}
```

Comment: Hi there, thanks, this is almost perfect. However, it is now saying temp_hours is NaN. Any idea how to remedy this?

Comment: This is strange because it works for me : http://jsfiddle.net/2Zy3U/ Can you add more info on your problem ? What is the origine of hours before being put on localStorage ? (do a alert(typeof hours);)

Comment: Just did the `alert(typeof hours)` and it comes up with string! I was sure the hours was an int as I did arithmetic on it previously, this is how it is created: 
`var hours = $('#shift_end_time').timepicker('getSecondsFromMidnight') - $('#shift_start_time').timepicker('getSecondsFromMidnight');
        
       if (hours < 0) {
           hours += 86400;
       }

       hours = (hours / 3600).toFixed(2);`

Also, didn't know about alert(typeof) so thanks for teaching me something new!

Comment: You are welcome ;) The problem is toFixed, it converts a number into a string. I guess you were looking for some rounding functions. Use the Math object in javascript. `hours = Math.round((hours/3600) * 100) / 100`

Comment: ahh right I see now, thanks for all your help, I've learned a lot and my assignment 'should' go smoothly now. Cheers